# How do I implement dragging from a Jetpack Compose application to somewhere outside?

Tags: kotlin, drag-and-drop, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I can write something like this in my Compose application:

```kotlin
var isDroppable by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val (textFieldValue, setTextFieldValue) = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }

TextField(
    value = textFieldValue,
    onValueChange = setTextFieldValue,
    modifier = Modifier
        .offset(500.dp, 100.dp)
        .requiredSize(200.dp, 200.dp)
        .border(4.dp, if (isDroppable) Color.Green else Color.Red)
        .onExternalDrag(
            onDragStart = { externalDragValue ->
                isDroppable = externalDragValue.dragData is androidx.compose.ui.DragData.Text
            },
            onDragExit = {
                isDroppable = false
            },
            onDrop = { externalDragValue ->
                isDroppable = false
                val dragData = externalDragValue.dragData
                if (dragData is androidx.compose.ui.DragData.Text) {
                    setTextFieldValue(textFieldValue.copy(
                        text = textFieldValue.text.substring(0, textFieldValue.selection.start) +
                            dragData.readText() +
                            textFieldValue.text.substring(textFieldValue.selection.end),
                        selection = TextRange(textFieldValue.selection.end)
                    ))
                }
            },
        )
)
```

I can then open Notepad, type some text, and drag that text into the Compose app.

My question is: How to get the opposite?

If I select some text in the Compose application, I should be able to drag it back to Notepad, either moving or copying it depending on whether Ctrl is held down, same as text components in native applications.